# How do I place dock on the side of the center monitor?

Tags: macos, dock, monterey

I run three monitors: left, right, and center. I would like the dock on the right edge of the center monitor. However, macOS likes to put in on the rightmost edge of the rightmost monitor.

How can I put the dock on the right edge of the center monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't.

The Dock must go against one 'outer edge'. It won't sit in the middle of a larger screen area comprised of multiple displays.

3rd party Dock 'replacers' could do this - I'm still using DragThing on an older Mojave Mac & have my 'dock' similar to how you'd like yours, on the right edge of my left-most display. However, it won't run on any newer macOS & I've yet to actually try this list of potential replacements I got from a question on our sister site,  [Software Recommendations - Dock-style app to replace DragThing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/58667/22850)